# BigQuery pricing when using gcloud

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud

I'm using `bq load...` to insert a `.json` file into my BigQuery dataset.

The pricing at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing suggests that:

> Loading data into BigQuery is free, with the exception of a small charge for streamed data

By using the CLI, I'm not sure exactly how the data is being inserted into the table, but I would imagine it's being added in bulk, not one at a time. Does anybody know for certain whether or not datafile insertion via the GC CLI would be considered streaming?

Comment: `bq load` is considered as a bulk load process. No cost associated. See here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bq load` means "load", so there is no cost associated with using it. You have to use `bq insert` to use the streaming API.